# Where to put the .join in this function in order to rejoin the separated strings of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Problem to solve is to capitlize the first letter of each word in a string using '.split' '.map' and 'join'. Currently implemented split and map to get the word capitlised and rejoined it, but confused as to where I need to put the .join.

```
Expected: "The Lord Of The Rings"
Received: ["The", "Lord", "Of", "The", "Rings"]
```

```js
function titleCase(string) {
  return string.split(' ').map(word => word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.substr(1))
  

}
```

Comment: What does map() return? It returns an array so your join would go after it if you want a string returned

Answer (score 2):

First: split the string

Second: Capitalize word

Third: Join  words

```
return string.split(' ').map(word => word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.substr(1)).join(' ');
```